# Redirect loop when forcing www. hostname and SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'm going crazy – I just checked and rechecked my rules but I still don't understand why the server is producing a redirect loop?

The goal is to force as well www. as SSL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine for incorrect URLs (either without www. or without SSL), but for correct ones I end up with a infinite redirect loop: `https://www.example.com/uiae -> https://www.example.com/uiae`

Is it possible that the server cannot handle the HTTPS-variable?

The Apache Documentation states that that variable would be safe to use for Apache 2.2.

I also tried `SERVER_PROTOCOL !=https` with the same result.

Without my rules I can access as well HTTP as HTTPS URLs, which shows that there is no other rules outside of my .htaccess.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean WHAT redirects me? I'm using ```wget --server-response``` for analysis.

Comment: Btw the hosting provider is Strato

Comment: What code are you running? It might be doing it in your code. Some cms try to do the redirection itself and that would cause a loop.

Comment: It's the Contao CMS, **but**: if I remove my rewrite-rules, the correct url is **not** being redirected, hence there is no other redirect.

Comment: ```RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (uiae.uiae)$``` https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
also redirects https://example.com/uiae.uiae

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the hosting provider (in that case Strato.de) messed around with the support of that variable.

Their statement was

> Strato does not support this variable

Which was completely unexpected since it's a standard Apache-Variable, as the documentation states.

A workaround is to use the protocol instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```